# Tutorial 1.16 "ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv" with Catkin system build

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, service, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I started ROS tutorials, using catkin system as a workspace builder. I didn't had any issue until this tutorial examining service and client nodes.

After creating having written my service and client nodes in the previous tutorial, I tried to run them :

> $ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py

and i get this error :

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py",
> line 4, in 
> from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
>
> ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv"

I searched how to resolve this problem, but i didn't find an answer for catkin system build (for rosbuild, it seems like uncomment #rosbuild_genmsg() and #rosbuild_gensrv() lines on the CMakeLists.txt is enough).

However, there is no comments like that in my CMakeLists.txt (due to the fact I used catkin and not rosbuild).
I even tried to rebuild my workspace by erasing devel and build files in my catkin workspace, and rebuild it, but it didn't work.

I could use some help on this if you know how to do it. Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114806/tutorial-1.16-%22importerror:-no-module-named-beginner_tutorials.srv%22-with-catkin-system-build/) by [Polo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10466/polo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-04

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out in tutorial CreatingMsgAndSrv for message/service generation with catkin you need to:

- Add to package.xml:

  `<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>`
  `<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>`
- Add message_generation in CMakeLists.txt as REQUIRED catkin component (like any package, e. g. roscpp):

  `find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp message_generation )`
- uncomment add_message_files in CMakelists.txt and add your msg files with messages to be generated:

  `add_message_files( FILES my_message.msg )`
- uncomment add_service_files in CMakelists.txt and add your srv files with services to be generated:

  `add_service_files( FILES beginner_tutorials.srv )`
- uncomment generate_messages in CMakeLists.txt with packages containing msgs depending on:

`generate_messages( DEPENDENCIES std_msgs  )`

- in CMakeLists.txt add ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp as dependency of your target that required the message to be generated before being compiled (in C++, I am not sure if is also necessary for python)

`add_executable( foo_exec src/foo.cpp)`
`target_link_libraries( foo_exec ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )`
`add_dependencies( foo_exec ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp )`

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-19**:
Isn't the service called AddTwoInts.srv and not beginner_tutorials.srv ?

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-19**:
Yes, this is want mentioned tutorial says. Here a little abstracted necessary steps for message generation of any message with catkin

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-03-25**:
My issue was caused by jumping ahead in the tutorials. I had done the tutorials a while back and this time I did not take the time to go back through them all to build the CMakeList properly. Wolf, can you check your  *add_message_files( FILES beginner_tutorials.srv ) I think it's add_service_files

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-25**:
Oops, yes right, I changed. Thank you =)

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2015-08-25**:
I just got this same problem using rosbuild, and i had to change `from beginner_tutorials.srv import *` in the client.py to `"from rospy_tutorials.srv import *`. Am i sure this is correct? Not really, but everything else i tried failed.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-09-03**:
DEpends on how your package is named, if it's name is `rospy_tutorials` you are correct

**Comment by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on 2016-08-02**:
Hi I know its old but I would also add:

```
catkin_package( CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime )
```

It feels like it only works for me if I uncomment the line in the catkin_package section and add message runtime to it.

**Comment by [IsakEngström](https://answers.ros.org/users/58676/isakengstr%C3%B6m/) on 2020-08-27**:
**Note:** For `package.xml` files in [XML Format 2](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml#Format_2_.28Recommended.29), `run_depend` should instead be `exec_depend`, as pointed out [Here](https://answers.ros.org/question/283123/what-is-the-difference-between-exec_depend-and-run_depend/?answer=283131#post-id-283131).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wasn't apparent to me at first. After the `catkin_make` you have to source the devel/setup.bash file **again**, even if you've done so before in that terminal.

---

Originally posted by [dheater](https://answers.ros.org/users/27907/dheater/) with karma: 216 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sourcecreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/30120/sourcecreator/) on 2017-04-22**:
This worked for me.  I had already done everything described by @Wolf, but forgot this step.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

run this command    **source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash**  because your system needs to see the changes you make. ( for example,After the "**catkin_make** or  **catkin_make install**" command )

---

Originally posted by [Ahiska](https://answers.ros.org/users/32515/ahiska/) with karma: 11 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1